# "ATML U942", is it a 555 clone?

Tags: identification, 555

Was looking for 555's in my parts box, and while I did find one NE555, I found a dozen of these, in the same pouch. Wondering if the seller pushed me some slugs, because I can't find datasheet for this part. Not even in the Chinese / Russian parts search sites !!

The form-factor is same as NE555 (8 pin DIP), and markings on top say -

```
ATML U942
2FB 2
9H07258
```

and the bottom die sealant says that it's manf'd in Thailand.

Comment: Can you add a close-up of package?

Comment: ATML is the NASDAQ trading symbol for [Atmel](http://www2.atmel.com/), and they do have facilities in Thailand, so that could narrow your search.  They don't manufacture a 555, though they do manufacture plenty of 8-pin DIPs...

Comment: Thanks @KevinVermeer. Google was smarter than me, and did suggest 'Atmel' given the ticker symbol, and I did search Atmel site with U942 (which turns out to be the manf year/week id), and the production lot number, obviously not finding anything. I wonder if there was a better way to search.

Comment: @Curd, missed your comment. I thought of putting the image, but my primary camera is lent out to a friend, and alternative sucks bigtime with macros and low-light. If you believe you'd still like to see the image, let me know and I can post it in a few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an Atmel AT24C512B.  Two-wire Serial EEPROM, 2.5V, 512K (65,536 x 8).

See the [AT24C512B datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc5297.pdf) page 13 for markings.

Comment: Nice work!  ASCII art for the marking diagrams is rather strange, though...

Comment: Wow, now that's a lucky catch for me. 512K serial EEPROM for the price of NE555. Thanks @TevoD. BTW, I did search Atmel and U942 and google returned nothing. And as Kevin says, the marking diagram is rather strange, and no hint of the part.